# LINQ Where clause Multiple conditions

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, linq

Im trying to get all the data rows that contain a certain set of data.

In my database i have some values, including start and length.

I have an array that contains integers called startTimes and another called endTimes.

I need a where clause that would return the records that have a start value contained in startTimes, OR start+length contained in endTimes.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

```
    IQueryable<request> proposedRequest = db.requests.Include(r => r.rooms);
        proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(r=>r.booked.Equals(1));
        proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(r=>r.roundID.Equals(roundID))8;
        proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(r=>r.day.Equals(day));
        int[] startTimes;
        int[] endTimes;
        for(var q=0;q<time;q++){
            startTimes[startTimes.Length] = time + q;
            endTimes[endTimes.Length] = time + q + 1;
        }
        proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(//what goes in here);
```

Comment: @DawoodAwan added above ^^

Answer (score 2):

will something like this suffice?

```
var data = collection.Where(
        t => startTimes.Contains(t.theTime) || 
        endTimes.Contains(t.theTime + theLength));
```

Comment: i have an array startTime=[1,3,4] and an array endTime=[2,4,5] lets say. I need to see if any of those values match my records? I dont think the above would do the job, so if i could do (m=>m.startTime.isIn(startTimes)... then yes but i dont think that is possible

Comment: @user2976358 Added example with `Contains`, but I'm not clear on your variables/identifiers

Answer (score 2):

> i have an array startTime=[1,3,4] and an array endTime=[2,4,5] lets
>   say. I need to see if any of those values match my records? I dont
>   think the above would do the job

To check if you have value in Array of int, Use the Contains Method:

```
proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(s => startTimes.Contains(s.INT_ID) 
                                        || endTimes.Contains(s.INT_ID));
```

Syntax: `ARRAY.Contains(ID_TO_SEARCH)`

it returns a boolean:

```
var list = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};
var intVar = 4;
var exists = list.Contains(intVar);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proposedRequest.Where(pr => startTimesArray.Contains(pr.start) || endTimesArray.Contains(pr.start + pr.length));
```

Comment: Looks like someone beat me to it hahaha.